# Flipping rows and column values of a binary matrix to maximize the sum of all rows treated as binary numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

Given a binary matrix of 0's and 1's with m rows and n columns, we can flip the contents of the whole row or column any number of times. Rows are to be interpreted as binary numbers. How to flip the contents of rows/columns to maximize the sum of the 'm' binary numbers, each per row.

For example, matrix = [{0 0}, {1,0}], current sum of the rows = 0 + 2 = 2. After flipping the contents row wise of row 1, we get [{1,1}, {1,0}], sum of its rows = 3 + 2 = 5.

Link: https://leetcode.com/problems/score-after-flipping-matrix/

P.S.  I didn't come to know about this problem from this particular link, but verbally from someone. Later I found this link having the same question.

Comment: what is your question ? What you did by yourself ?

Comment: By "swap", you mean flip each bit?

Comment: @bruno, I tried to come up with a Dynamic Programming solution to this question but could not. My question is how to approach this problem?

Comment: @Carlos, yes flipping all the bits rows or column wise.

Comment: Ok so my initial observation is for a row, if it starts with a 0, flipping it will make the sum bigger. For a column it will get bigger if there are more 0s than 1s. Is that right?

Comment: This sounds like a "competition" site problem. While it's good that you include the problem description and an example here on SO, also please add a link to the actual problem itself. Also please try to create a [mcve] of *your own attempt*. And please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Carlos, yes this approach should work. Looks like I was heading in wrong direction. Greedy approach should be applied here. Thanks!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thanks for sharing the useful tips about asking questions!

Comment: @JackR Problem link?

Comment: Added link to the problem

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this is not a competition problem.

Comment: There's a solution page on the link.

Comment: @Carlos, I didn't come to know about this problem from this particular link, but verbally from someone. Later I found this link having the same question.

Answer (score 2):

The order in which we toggle the rows and columns doesn't matter. Toggling a row or column more than once is pointless.

Since the constraints are narrow, we can try the at most 2<sup>20</sup> possibilities for toggling a subset of columns, then for each possibility toggle the rows that have a leading zero since that's the best we can do given our choice of columns.

Comment: should we toggle only those columns wherein the number of 0's are greater than 1's instead of trying all 2^20 possibilities. Thanks!

Comment: @JackR 2^20 is only about one million. My intuition is that there's a case where that optimization misses an optimal solution.